# AWB not confident

Tags: android, android-camera, qcar-sdk

I have been involved in the problem with android camera in Logcat.
After I launch and exit the application using QCAR and camera, the android gives out errors to logcat.
The error is following, and the same errors continue to be given out continuously until I turn off the android device.

```
09-24 15:25:45.467: E/mm-camera(194): c2d_thread_handle_process_buf_event:265 failed: pp_buf_mgr_get_buf()
```

Does someone know what causes this error?
I'm using new Android Nexus7, and Android OS version is 4.3.

Answer (score 3):

Did you release the camera instance in your application? For example, can you start the standard camera app after exiting your own?

If you're not calling [Camera.release()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#release%28%29) in your app's `onPause` handler, then the camera will keep running, and the lower levels of the Nexus 7 camera stack log a lot of non-error information under the E log level, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I checked my code and found that Camera.release() was not always called. Thank you for your advise!